# Плавно переместить блок при уменьшении ширины браузера

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Стоит такая задача:

1. Имеем несколько div (например, 5) у каждого `float:left` =>, они все расположены в строчку в окне браузера.
2. Если уменьшать ширину браузера, то крайний левый div будет смещен (моментально) на 2-ю строку, а следом и еще один div на 2-ю строку и т. д.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы в момент перемещения крайнего блока он перемешался плавно (animate) и не наезжал на другие блоки, те и другие блоки смещались, а-ля пятнашки.

Вот тут картинки, если я совсем туго выразился...
Имеем:

[image: Imgur]

Время Ч:

[image: Imgur]

Как должно быть:

[image: Imgur]

Подскажите что-нибудь?
Заранее благодарен за любой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Юзайте современные технологии, без каких либо JS скриптов - CSS3 Media Queries: [тык](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) / [Хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119127/).

А если хотите на JS, то (jQuery):

```
    $( window ).resize(function() {
      // Ваш код
     // например: $('.div-5').css() и 
    });
```

Comment: Значит, даже с использованием JS, оперировать все равно css свойствами?
Спасибо за помощь, буду изучать.

Comment: @ka5itoshka? ещё один... Tсли хочется анимацию (тем более такую сложную), то media queries - мимо.

Answer (score 0):

> Задача состоит в том, что бы в момент
> перемещения крайнего блока он
> перемешался плавно (animate) и не
> наезжал на другие блоки, те и другие
> блоки смещались, а-ля пятнашки.

Если Вас интересуют плавное перемещение, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону [CSS3 Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Comment: Меня не удивляет ответ @erbolking, т.к. возможно, он и не понял задачу. Но удивляет то, что за этот ответ уже понаставили плюсов. Это ж каким боком поможет transitions для поставленной задачи? Самое интересное, что даже перейдя по ссылке, которую указал отвечающий, можно прочитать в первом предложении, что это свойство позволяет добавлять эффект при изменении стиля элемента. А какое свойство стиля меняется у элемента, который показан на последнем скрине в вопросе, не подскажите?

Answer (score -1):

```
* {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```